# Design of queryable web based results

Tags: c#, wcf, iqueryable

I'm trying to accomplish something like a facebook news feed wall, loading N number of results from the overall dataset, starting with the most recent, date descending. When you click “more”, it displays the next N underneath and so on until you finish the dataset.

I’m struggling to come up with the best design to accomplish this. Ive always been told that stateless web services are the only way to build a scalable enterprise application, which means that as I understand it, keeping the whole results object cached serverside on the first call to the page, and just taking N results from it with each subsequent web service call is a no no?

If that’s the case, then something like GetResults(int pageindex, int pagesize) would work.... and thats how I WAS going to do it but then I realised it would not work if someone added a new DB record in between calls. Eg you start with 23 wall feed items in the DB and want to display them 10 at a time.

- First call, page 1, page size 10 will return results 14-23 (most recent first)
- Someone then adds 2 new posts, so you have 25 now in the DB
- Second call, page 2, page size 10 will return results 6-15, two of which were already returned in the first call.

So this offsetting approach doesn’t work because you can’t guarantee the underlying dataset will remain the same between calls.

Im confused, how do I accomplish this?

Edit: Sorry a little more info. To avoid the problem of huge data table lookups, I had considered the option of pre-populating a "transient" table with the last few days data for that user when you first load the screen, then just reading the results a page at a time from that transient table to make it faster reading, with a slightly slower load time. Then when you exhaust that data, you bring in the next period (say 2 weeks) into the transient table and continue reading.

The difficulty is that users will "Post" items which then automatically will be picked up by users who match their search criteria. Eg if your criteria state you want to meet people between 25 and 32 and within 50 miles of you, then when you load up your news feed, you want it to show posts from all users who match your criteria. Kindof like a dynamic friends list.

How I was going to achieve this was at time of login, a stored proc would run which would populate a transient table in the DB by selecting all users and filtering down based on age and location criteria which I have in static lookup tables (postcode distances etc), then it will save the list of Users who match your criteria to this transient table for use whenever you then need to filter posts or search users. If you update your preferences, it will also recalculate this but only when you update prefs or re-login. So any new users signing up won't appear until you next login, which is fine I think.

Then when it comes time to display your news feed, all it does is retrieves this list of User Ids from the DB who match your criteria, then brings back all NewsFeedPosts which were posted by those users. Hey presto, dynamic news feed!

But obviously this is a subset of the entire NewsFeedPost table which is generated on the fly, so it doesn't make sense to recalculate this every time a user clicks "more", so this was how I was thinking about implementing it.

Tables - NewsFeedCurrent, NewsFeedRecent, NewsFeedArchive
New posts are created in the current table. Every night a batch job runs that moves all data from current that is 2 days old, to the recent table, and any data in the recent table that is a week old to the archive table.

The thinking being that 90% of the time, the user will only be interested in the last 2 days of data. So keep table small for access time. Another 9% of the time the user may want the last weeks data. So keep that separate in a secondary table. Then only 1% of the time the user wants data more than a week old so keep that in a larger, slow archive table that will be slower, but gives you performance boost by keeping current and recent tables small.

So when you first hit the news feed page, what it was going to do is take the pre-generated user list for your account and pull out all NewsFeedCurrent items and put them in a transient table, say TempNewsFeed under your user ID. You can then work with this resultset just by pulling back everything for your user id, no filtering required for items you arent interested in as they are pre-filtered. this will add a second or so to the page load but will improve response time when fetching results. Then when that data is exhausted, it will then - again using the list of users matching your criteria - pull out all relevant data from the Recent table, adding it to the TempNewsFeed table, allowing you to continue fetching data up to a week old. When thats exhausted, it will finally go to the archive table and using the user id list, pull out all data matching this and put in the temp table, allowing you to continue navigating the remaining data. This will give a fairly significant delay as it populates the archive data but if you are going back a week, then you will have to accept 5-10 seconds wait while it populates the data and says "loading data...". Once it has though, navigating historical data will be just as quick as recent data as it will all be in the transient table.

If you refresh the screen or go back onto it from another screen, it clears out the transient table and starts again from the Current table data.

Answer (score 0):

Hope my answer makes sense, makes the right assumptions ...

I would divide the news feed into two sections.  The first is for incoming news - which would be powered with AJAX calls.  It is constantly saying "What is new?"  The second section is for older news, where the user can lazily load more news by scrolling down.

**Newest News Items**

The important point is to make note of the maximum news feed id on your page.  Let's imagine that is 10000.  When the user loaded the page, news feed id 10000 was the latest news item.

When the new section is updated with AJAX, we simply ask, "What is newer than id 10000?" and we load those items onto the page.  After we load them, we also increment the id on the page.  For example, if we start with id 10000 and we load five new news items, the new id would be 10005.  The next call would ask, "What is newer than 10005?"

**Older News Items**

The older section would keep track of the oldest news item on the page.  Let's imagine they scroll back for a weeks worth of news.  The minimum news item id would be 9000.  When they want to scroll back further, we simply ask, "What is older than 9000?"

The idea then is to maintain on the page the maximum news item id and the minimum news item id and then keep loading from that reference point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This seems nice and simple. The only thing I wonder about is the access time if this is a table used by tens of thousands of users or more, with loads of posts. It's definitely a very good option, I've just edited my post above with a method I was considering trying but now weighing it up with your solution. What do you think of my edit?

Comment: Just finished reading your edit.  I agree with the concept of archiving older data.  This is a good idea because you are correct that users will most likely only be interested in the most recent activity.  You give them access to older stuff, but at a price (speed).  Be open to relaxing the real time requirement and allowing for inconsistent data.  All big systems do this.  If a user they are friends with posts something, it's ok for it to take a minute or so to show up in the feed.  Users can't see the entire system at once, so they won't know what they're missing.

Comment: I would be careful with adding too many moving parts to the system.  It's a good idea when wanting speed to pre-process data. I think you hinted at that with having your transient table. Sometimes when making a design the more "hacks" you have to add, the more it should suggest the design is a bit flawed.  Sometimes a compromise in the UI can ease the design.  Consider how easy having all these transient tables will be to maintain. Don't underestimate how fast a well tuned database can be. Try to resist the temptation to pre-maturely optimize. Bottlenecks can be in places that are surprising.